# How to insert public url from image stored in AWS S3 into JSX component?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I am trying to receive public URLs of images, which are stored in a AWS S3 Storage like this: `Storage.get(imageKey)` => Promise

But I am having problems storing the returned value of that promise.

Here's my code

```
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify'

class Images extends Component {

  getImgUrl = async key => {
    return Storage.get(key)
    .then(res => (res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {arrayWithObjects.map(({img}) => (
          <img src={this.getImgUrl(img)} />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

With this code I am receiving "[object Promise]" in src. Which makes sense, but I can't figure out how to get the actual URL which is returned in the resolver of `Storage.get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify'

const getImgUrl = key => {
    return Storage.get(key)
    .then(res => (res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

class Image extends Component {
   this.state = {
     imgSrc: null
   }

  componentDidMount(){
      getImgUrl(this.props.img).then(src => {
        this.setState({imgSrc: src});
      });
   }

  render() {

     if(!this.state.imgSrc) {
       return null;
     }

       return <img src={this.state.imgSrc} />;
    }
}

class Images extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {arrayWithObjects.map(({img}) => (
          <Image img={img} />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```